distorted narrow lens image can't be undistorted with opencv?
Overview:
The image was obtained using a ids camera on a wide field lens, roughly 15-25 images are loaded in, the output from the normal openCV functions were just giving me an identical image. Thus, the fisheye functions are used here without success.
            #obtains the object 3D vectors
            number_ro_co=self.find_modulus(number_of_impoints)
            objp = np.zeros((number_ro_co[0]*number_ro_co[1],3), np.float32)
            objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:number_ro_co[0],0:number_ro_co[1]].T.reshape(-1,2)
            objp=np.float32(objp)

            for i in im_corners3:
                x,y = i.ravel()
                cv.circle(img,(x,y),3,255,-1)
            
            
            if np.any(im_corners):
                
                #appends the list with no nan values
                object_list.append(objp)
                
            else:
                cv.error()


        

        object_list=np.expand_dims(np.asarray(object_list),-2) 
        #obtains the intrinsic matrix
        ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs= cv.fisheye.calibrate(object_list, img_points, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)

        print(mtx)
        print(dist)
        h,w=gray.shape[:2]
        
        newcameramtx = cv.fisheye.estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify(mtx, dist, (w,h),np.eye(3),None,1)

        print(newcameramtx)
    

        img0=cv.imread("path_removed")
        
        #obtains the refined intrinsic matrix using a scaling factor
        h, w = img0.shape[:2]
        

        #rectifies the image
        dst=cv.fisheye.undistortImage(img0,mtx,dist,None,newcameramtx)
        

        # crops the image
       
        plt.imshow(dst);plt.show()


Please look at the code and give me constructive advice.

can't calibrate on a single image. -- watch your point pairs. they might not match up

As you might have seen in the overview of this post, 15-25 images are loaded in. I only wanted to provide you one example. For me it seems reasonable why I don‘t share the 15-25 images

the entire set of calibration images might be unsuitable. I can't tell unless I see at least thumbnails. -- your code does not show how img_points is defined. [mre] required.

My main concern is that, the calibration or undistortion method bugs, and not the corners because opencv finds every corner, there are later converted into float32 & put into a list of list: img_points

Mainly, all images look similar-but not completely equivalent with rotation or other corners distorted

in that case, they can't be used for calibration. let's just go with that, until you show someone your dataset, at least as thumbnails

follow-up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78617152/calibration-or-rectification-is-not-working-properly
